# How to modify the description of products in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php

I have a simple plugin in magento 2 that modifies the name of the products, but I can not find the function that modifies the description

```
public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
{
   return '|' . $result . ' - Test';
}
```

So modified the names of the products, I also have the function to modify the prices but what is the function to modify the description?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin for all setter getters from product model. So to change description you can use

```
public function afterGetDescription(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
{
   return '|' . $result . ' - Test';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the `getData($key)` function. They usually call `getDescription()` or `getData("description")` to get the description.

Basically, in the system it always calls `getData("description")` function so you can modify that function to change the result.